# Virtual Machine how to use your installed Windows programs on VMware or VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtual-desktop

When you have Windows 10 and want to use a VM like VMware or VirtualBox (VM is also Windows 10), do you have to install your existing applications a second time on the drive of that new VM you created? Or is there some "button" to click where you can decide if you want to run an app on the VM or in "normal" mode? For example the Internet Explorer browser. What do I have to do to use it within the VM?

And is there any security vulnerability known when comparing VMware vs VirtualBox, any preference?

Thanks

Comment: A guest operating system, running within a VM, is separate from the host OS.  Security vulnerabilities exist for both Oracle (VirtualBox) and VMWare virtualization products.  Security vulnerabilities that exist in those products, like any software, are routinely fixed.

Comment: Seperate from what @Ramhound says (which is not wrong).. No magic "button".. but you can indeed run a HOST's apps on the GUEST ASSUMING that 1)You have shared the host file system with the guest so the guest can get to the file. 2)The application can run without installation (stand-alone). and 3)The application is launched from the guest.  It is really no different than if you had a network share with an exe in it run from another machine.